# NodeJS converting string to variable

Tags: string, node.js, variables

I am trying to update the contents of a variable in nodejs with the use of a string.
In client side javascript this was done with the use of window[variable] however since there is no "window" in nodejs. I tried using "this" and "module", however all im getting is an empty object. need help thanks

Code Snippet:

```
var myVariable = 'Hello';
var exchangeVariable = 'myVariable';

this[exchangeVariable] = 'Hello World';

/*
    myVariable should equal to 'Hello World!'
*/
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's your purpose for accessing the variable in such a way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's some background before I answer your question directly:

In JavaScript, objects can be either indexed by the dot notation (`someObj.property`) or by indexing them as you do in your example (`someObj["property"]`)

In the browser, `window` is the global context that the browser evaluates your code within.  Node uses a [variable called `global`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.15/api/globals.html#globals_global).

So, if you want to reference a variable you've defined globally:

```
> var someGlobalVar = "hi";
> var myLookupKey = "someGlobalVar";
> global[myLookupKey]
'hi'
```

**However, this is generally considered very bad practice** (in Node and the browser).  There are a myriad of reasons for this, but I'm focusing on just one:

In Node, modules (each `require`d file) should be treated as if they do not share global state (and in some cases, they cannot share state).  I encourage you to read through the [modules section](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.15/api/modules.html) of the node documentation if you are trying to share state across files.

Comment: Strange that this answer is voted down... It LGTM, at least to stay at 0. I'd vote it up just for the "Day of The tentacle" avatar ;)

Comment: It always makes me smile when someone recognizes it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own variables hash or array and assign the variable yourself.

```
var myVariable = "Hello";
var varArray = new Array()
    varArray["exchangeVariable"] = myVariable;
```

Comment: Why an `Array`?  A blank object would be a lot more applicable to this use.  You're not taking advantage of any of Array's behavior here

Comment: I said hash or array, I don't know of his use case. I just chose to write an array as an example.